# Continue or Resume?

Tags: wording

When presenting an opportunity for a user to continue an application process (the words are in a navbar) is 'resume...' considered worse than 'continue...' because 'resume' can be momentarily misunderstood to be a noun rather than a verb?

Answer (score 3):

It should not cause any confusion, given that the context makes it clear that it is not a noun.

The real difference between "resume" and "continue" in UX is whether or not the user paused the task and launching it again (resume) or simply going to the next step (continue).

> Resume = start again from the point where you stopped.
>
> Continue = go to the next step.

Comment: Jason, I fully agree with Sylverdrag. As an additional comment, "resume" has exactly one meaning when used as a noun, and unless you're working on a product related to hiring, the chance of confusing your users with the use of that term should be near zero. ;) If you _are_ using it as a noun, spelling it properly with accents — résumé — will further enforce the differentation between noun and verb.

Comment: @JochenW Maybe I should have phrased my question more clearly - I know the user will almost definitely figure out which one is intended, but for a brief moment the user may have to think about it, and I'm wondering if that brief second of having to think makes it inferior UX to 'continue' which requires zero thought - as soon as the user sees the word 'continue' the user knows what it is.

Comment: The possible confusion with the noun is possibly location dependent. Being in the UK, I don't think I'd ever see "_resume_" and think of it as a noun (unless, perhaps, I was on job site, and even then I might not initially think so if it didn't have an accent).